# An abelian group $G$ whose subgroup $H \cong \mathbf{Q}^+$ has $G \cong \mathrm{Q}^+ \times G/H$?

Tags: group-theory

[Edit: $\mathbf{Q}^+$ is additive group of rationals]

Title question is from an old textbook. I tried creating some sort of injective homomorphism $f:G/H \to G$, to get some kind of canonical subgroup representation in $G$ for elements of $G/H$, which would enable me to define homomorphisms from from $H \times G/H$ to $G$ in a controlled way. To do that, I tried applying Zorn lemma to get a maximal subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/H$, but I'm stuck/unsure how to be certain I won't always get $\{0\}$ or something.

I also tried just finding an injective homomorphism $f:G \to \mathbf{Q}^+$ directly but that seems to be a hornet's nest.

Comment: What is $Q^+$? The multiplicative group of positive rationals?

Comment: The additive group of rationals.

Comment: What's wrong with $G = H = Q^+$

Comment: The result you want is that divisible abelian groups are injective: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01D6

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Nothing, I only realized there's actually no contradiction in general after posting. I mistakenly thought the existence of homomorphism from $\mathbf{R}^+$ to $\mathbf{Q}^+$ would imply $\mathbf{R}^+ \cong \mathbf{Q}^+ \times \mathbf{Q}^+$.

Comment: Andrzej Białynicki-Birula, "Zarys algebry", 1987